# Excel button that writes down the time of clicking

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make list of times in Excel Spreadsheets.
The idea is to have 4 buttons in the spreadsheet that will write down the time of clicking of each button.

Each button will represent a different group, and I wish to have a list of the times I pressed each button so I could check and research about the groups activity.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and an example of what your trying to get.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hAw8QzC8I1andaeFlfNjAwdnc/edit?usp=sharing
that's what i wanna have, on each button press i want it to add the time of pressing to a different spreadsheet. 
sory for linking couldnt find where to attach the file here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new module in your VBE and stick this in there:

   ```
   Sub capturetime()

     Dim timeWS As Worksheet
     Dim timeRange As Range

     'Change "Sheet3" to whatever worksheet is your click log
     Set timeWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

     'find the last cell in column A of your log
     Set timeRange = timeWS.Range("A" & timeWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

     'Write which button was clicked in column A
     timeRange.Value = Application.Caller

     'Write the time in column B
     timeRange.Offset(, 1).Value = Now()

   End Sub
   ```
2. Edit the values as necessary in that code.
3. Create a button using Developer>>(Controls)Insert. Find the button in there. The "Form" button is fine.
4. Draw the button on the screen somewhere. And, when it prompts you to assign a macro, choose "capturetime"

This bit of VBA will grab the name of the button that was pressed and the time and write it to whatever worksheet you select as the your log. It's pretty simple, so it shouldn't be a bother to mess with it to fit your needs.